# How to setup DrillInNavigationTransition?

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation, transition

Iam trying to use the Transition in UWP 
I added the OnBackRequested() method in the App.xaml.cs

```
    private void OnbackRequested(Object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if(rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack(new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
        }
    }
```

and set the name of the Frame name in MainPage is rootFrame
But nothing is happen

Answer (score 1):

Your page has to have `NavigationThemeTransition` for this to work:

```
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition />
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

Ideally both pages (the source and the destination) should include this declaration.